# A cubic polynomial $p(x)$ satifies the following conditions:$p(-2)=-25, p(-1)=5, p(1)=-1,p(2)=11$ . Compute $p(0)$.

Tags: polynomials

I am not very familiar with calculating functions, and have no idea where to start. Can somebody lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Read up on [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).  Note:  you have written $p(2)=-25$ and $p(2)=11$ but I assume one of those should be $p(-2)$.

Comment: Have you ever seen a book whose title replaces the first sentence?

Comment: Expression-wise, what does $p(x)$ being a cubic polynomial tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Write $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx  + d$, which can be done since $p$ is cubic. Now, substitute the values given to you:
\begin{gather}
-8a + 4b - 2c + d = -25 \\
-a+b-c+d = 5 \\
a+b+c+d = -1 \\
8a+4b+2c+d = 11
\end{gather}

Solve for $a,b,c,d$. Note that $f(0) = d$, so all you need to do is find $d$.

Solution :(Hidden)

> $a=4,b=-3,c=-7,d=5$, then the answer should be $f(0) = d = 5$.

Comment: Im not quite sure how you substituted in. WHat would I substitute in for $x^3, x^2,x$?

Comment: If $x = 2$, then you would substitute in $2^3,2^2,2$ for $x^3,x^2,x$ respectively. That is how a function works, right? $f(2)$ is computed by replacing $x$ with $2$ everywhere in $f$. So that's what I did above,for four different values.

Comment: But wouldn't the values be different for different values of x?

Comment: It would. So for example, if I want $f(1)$, I substitute $1$ for $x$ above, I would get $1^3a +1^2b+1c+d$, which is the same as $a+b+c+d$. However,  if I want $f(2)$, I substitute $2$ for $x$ above, and I would get $2^3a+2^2b+2c+d$, which is of course different from $f(1)$.

Comment: How did you go from step 2 to step 3 in your equation?

Comment: There are no steps. I have just written down $f(-2),f(-1),f(1),f(2)$ in that order, by just substituting $-2,-1,1,2$ for $x$. Since we know the values of $f(-2),$etc. I just put these four equalities together. There is no order there.